# Can not get Set Cookie value python requests headers

Tags: python, python-requests, e-commerce

I am trying to get a particular cookie from a request that I can see being set in browser through a particular endpoint which is like this

```
https://www.store.com/cart/miniCart/TOTAL?_=1591997339780
```

these are the response headers I see through Chrome Dev Tools

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
CF-RAY: 5a26c442fb22801a-SAN
cf-request-id: 034c18fddd0000801ac6b42200000001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: es
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2020 21:46:48 GMT
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: cloudflare
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=18A8A12169ED6472A7359160F663CCF8; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: store-cart=d49a003e-41b5-444a-a71d-26b6f8db201c; Expires=Sun, 09-Nov-2031 13:46:48 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: AWSELB=11E5B3D30C8ACAF6D3240C8807474BBC740A29E2E0C61131788A04E3E6A646357EAA774C0A57B3DA33B571BADB93658470F13A3C847B4477CA237BB286CE5F3813ACBA53EEB69427F5D135043AFB3B2DC4835F3057;PATH=/;SECURE;HTTPONLY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 www.innvictus.com
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

but through Python requests I get the following headers only with response.headers using exact request headers in my browser and in my code

```
{'Date': 'Fri, 12 Jun 2020 21:56:36 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'Content-Language': 'es', 'Expires': '0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=66AA2037611590192D2E13C38FF65289; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, AWSELB=11E5B3D30C8ACAF6D3240C8807474BBC740A29E2E0D0EAFB9AD200F275E3F63597988B98E611188683EDE09A5FA437554B92ECADED7B4477CA237BB286CE5F3813ACBA53EEF44544C6AD7FBBF8C242FCAC378603C5;PATH=/;SECURE;HTTPONLY', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains', 'Via': '1.1 www.store.com', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'cf-request-id': '034c21f9160000e6f09b961200000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '5a26d2a1beb9e6f0-EWR', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

the cookie I need is the "store-cart=d49a003e-41b5-444a-a71d-26b6f8db201c; Expires=Sun, 09-Nov-2031 13:46:48" cookie but as you can see not in the dictionary I get with response.headers

Comment: It means that this cookie have been set in response of any other request. Or server detected your requests as automatically generated. Or any other reason. Set up debugging proxy server (Frida, Charles, etc.) and try to repeat everything from private tab in browser. It would be much easier to find needed request.

Comment: it can be good idea to use `requests.Session()` and first load main page to get Cookies. Of course if Cookie is created by JavaScript then `reuqests` is useless.

Comment: BTW: did you check what you get in HTML ? Maybe you get warning for bots/scripts ?

Comment: I did try to load the homepage itself first because I checked all network activity through Postman's requests interceptor log and it turns out that I found 2 requests to homepage ininitally `https://store.com` which somehow already has a `__cfuid` cookie in request and sets 2 more store related cookies. right after that there is another request sent to homepage `https://www.store.com` which sets the store-cart cookie that I need. but when i mimic this in my code it still doesn't give me the cookie. however i am still missing the first __cfuid cookie in the very first request

Comment: and i don't get any bot/scripts errors I get the store home page normally, I can actually still do various things with the site that I normally do such as add item to cart, login to account, but I need this cookie to save an address to an account and that's when I hit a 404 response pretty sure because I'm not getting the store-cart cookie

Answer (score 1):

Python requests doesn't parse cookies correctly.
See open issue: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6344

Here's my quick hack work-around:

```
def parse_cookies(response, session):
    """
    requests package doesn't parse cookies correctly. :-(
    parse them here and add to cookie jar
    """
    setcookie = response.headers['Set-Cookie']
    if (setcookie != None):
        # can't just split on , because the date format in expires attr has commas.
        # ... expires=Wed, 22 Feb...
        # so strip the commas from the expires dates first.
        setcookie = re.sub(r"expires=(...), ", r"expires=\1 ", setcookie)
        for cookie in setcookie.split(','):
            name, value = cookie.strip().split(';')[0].split('=')
            print({name : value})
            requests.utils.add_dict_to_cookiejar(session.cookies, {name : value})
```

Just call this after every response that sets cookies.

- response is the return value from session.post(...)
- session is the return value from requests.session()

**Note**: It doesn't set expiration dates or paths on the cookies.